# Replacing missing missing view count when photo

Tags: pandas, data-cleaning, preprocessing

I'm currently analyzing a dataset of posts on Facebook. Some are videos and others are photos. One of the features is view_count which has missing values every time the post is a photo. How can I replace those missing values? Can I put 0 views?

Answer (score 0):

It is NOT a good idea to replace these missing values with 0 because 0 represents "black". Instead of using 0, you can simply replace each missing value with the mean (average) of the surrounding missing values. Thus if you have 10 missing values, you should replace these with 10 various mean values.

Comment: But those are not missing values at random so we can't do that

Comment: Bingo! Because these missing values are not missing at random, this means these NA are  highly correlated its surrounding values. So replace each missing value with the mean of its surrounding values only. You are not replace all missing values with ONE mean value. If you have 10 missing values, you should replace with 10 different mean values based on the corresponding surrounding values.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks! Could I use the KNN imputer in that case?

Comment: Yes, it is a reasonable approach. BTW, if you think my solution help your problem, please hit up & accept my answer. Thanks